# How to delete VM that doesn't exist in Azure

Tags: azure

A VM running in my Azure subscription was deleted and no longer shows up in the portal. However the NIC and disk are still attached to it, and until I'd disassociated the public IP I could still access the site it was publishing. I want to delete everything in the resource group, but cannot due to this issue.

Get-AzVM returns 'ResourceNotFound', although Get-AzNetworkInterface still shows the ID of the problematic VM. The NIC and disk still reference the missing VM but clicking on that doesn't load anything. Remove-AzVM doesn't have any effect. Attempts to delete the NIC or disk fail because of their attachment to the VM that shouldn't exist.

Has anyone had this issue? Is there a way to get Azure support involved without having a support plan?

Comment: you'd need someone who can untangle conspiracy theories for this one. if the vm was deleted - nothing can reference it. although, why do you think it was deleted? maybe you just dont have access to view it

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. For any specific problem you are having please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Also, be sure to take the stackoverflow.com/tour (you get a badge!)

Comment: Your issue is probably due to lack of access, if you dont have access to the VM it will tell you that there is no VM like that. If your access persists then i suggest you contact MS Support.

Comment: The sequence of events were the VM was created in the portal, then connected to via terminal using it's public IP once the deployment was complete. But the VM never actually appeared in the portal, only the rest of the dependencies such as disk, NIC, IP address. I checked the activity log of the resource group and it said that it was deleted by the user that created it, however it was still accessible. Both myself and that user are global administrators so I doubt it's an access issue. 
Edit: It is currently still running but is just a ghost in Azure at this point.